# How to update only one module in multi module project

Tags: sonarqube, multi-module

I have a multi module project in which each module is written in different languages. I have added this project as a multi module project in local sonar instance according to the [sonar documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Advanced+SonarQube+Scanner+Usages) in which each sub module having separate sonar-project.properties file.

Anyway I wanted to analyse only one module because other modules doesn't have any changes. For that I have to add the project key to the sonar.project-properties file in the module which I wanted to analyse. But when I analyse the project using sonar scanner, analysis failed and below error can be seen in server logs. So is there anyway to analyse only one module in multi module project?

```
org.sonar.api.utils.MessageException: Validation of project failed:
  o Component (uuid=AV7hl7plAY-wqGulFkbZ, key=child-key) is not a project
  o The project "child-key" is already defined in SonarQube but as a module of project "parent-project-key". If you really want to stop directly analysing project "parent-project-key", please first delete it from SonarQube and then relaunch the analysis of project "child-key".
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having analyzed the modules together as one project, you cannot then go back and analyze only one of them. All modules must be analyzed together *or* you must delete your aggregate project to allow module analysis on an individual basis.

<sup>Note that the Governance($) plugin would allow you to re-aggregate your split modules</sup>

Comment: Even though it says commercial, I can download it from this page https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Governance+Plugin. Is there any license to get to use this plugin?

Comment: @lakshman I you are looking for a license, you should contact SonarSource's sales team https://www.sonarsource.com/forms/governance.html